# "I am keeping going with my father way" sounds like native speaker?

Tags: sentence-choice

His father passed away, and now he is trying to say the that he is keep going in his father way, that was honest and good person. Is the following sentence sounds corresponded?

> "I am keeping going with my father way"

Comment: You mean, "He wants to follow **his father's 'footsteps'**"?

Comment: I don't know if that's exactly what he means, but it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I am keeping going with my father's way.

If you continue something without stopping, or to do it repeatedly, you use "keep + `-ing`" form of a verb. So the correct sentence is:

> I keep going with my father's way.